# NewRelic support for Netty 4

Tags: java, netty, newrelic

I am using Netty 4 on Java 7and was looking into NewRelic for some basic web metrics.

I've implemented some rudimentary support via newrelic api, but I was wondering if someone has managed to get Netty 4 working with newrelic out of the box, or perhaps via a clever Netty channel handler.

Newrelic java agent automatically instruments Netty 3.5, but they do not mention anything about Netty 4.  So I suspect there is no native library.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right now we only support Netty 3.5.
We want to support Netty 4 in the future, but don't have a date for it yet.

When we release an agent with Netty 4 support, we'll have the notes on our [documentation page](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/java)

Comment: Is there any progress update on supporting netty 4? my company is building a new business backed by Netty 4.

Comment: Does it support netty 3.10.0.Final?

Comment: Support for Netty 4.x was introduced in version 3.22.0 of the New Relic Java Agent. https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/java-release-notes/java-agent-3220